# How to Resolve "Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component". React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, api, error-handling, use-effect

**ERROR  Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.**

```
   useEffect(() => {
     userIsRegister();
     if (sendMessage === '') {
       getAllMessage();
     }
    }, [sendMessage, isFocused]);
```

Comment: @muhammadusman- let me know if the answer given responds to your query.

Answer (score 1):

As error indicates, the react is being updated while component is already unmounted. It seems that some async task is returned after component is unmounted.

As mentioned in error, you can find out those and used the useEffect's clean-up method. Another way can be to useRef variable to maintain the component mounted state and execute the useEffect body only if component is still mounted.

```
  // A flag to make sure that the component is still mounted before updating the state for async operation.
  const isComponentMounted = useRef(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    isComponentMounted.current = true;
    return () => {
      isComponentMounted.current = false;
    };
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
     if (isComponentMounted.current) {
        userIsRegister();
        if (sendMessage === '') {
          getAllMessage();
        }
      }
  }, [sendMessage, isFocused]);
```